# How to get a substring using regex in Java ?

Tags: java, regex

Here is my String

```
 "fulladdress" : "210 Main Ln, Chicago, DE 72123, USA",
            "destination" : "whatever . 
            ....
```

Here is my Code . I am trying to get substring between `"fulladdress" :` and `",`

```
 String myString =   "],\n" + 
        "\"fulladdress\" : \"210 Main Ln, Chicago, DE 72123, USA\",\n" + 
        "\"destination\" : \"whatever . " + 
        ".... " ; 
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\"fulladdress\" :).*$\",\n"); 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString); 
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));  
        }
```

But this does not give me `210 Main Ln, Chicago, DE 72123, USA`

How can I improve this ?

Comment: Remove anchor `^` from your regex.

Comment: That looks like JSON. Don't use regex to parse it.

Comment: It is JSON, I used `json.org` library to parse it. But I don't want to use an external lib for this simple task. i want to get that address in a simple way

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `^` (star) and `$` (end) anchors since the pattern you want to match is between the string.

Use the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\"fulladdress\" :).*\",\n");
```